# How do I replace "br" tags in axios response with actual "br" tags?

Tags: reactjs, axios, wordpress-rest-api

using: React, WordPress REST API, Axios

I'm pulling results from a custom post type and when I get the results for the field "acf.other" which is a textbox field, whenever the user inputs a return, it puts either (depending on the cpt settings) a `<br />` tag, `</p> <p>` tags, or nothing, resulting in a running paragraph w/ no formatting. If it puts the tags, then the results show the tag on the site, and doesn't actually use the tags (see img).[screenshot of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoomD.png)

```
export const SingleRecent = () => {
    const { singleSlug } = useParams();
    const [single,setSingle] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(recent + singleSlug)
        .then(response => {
            setSingle(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    
    }, [singleSlug]);
    
    return (
        <><div className="pagebg singlePageBg">
            <main>
                <div className="container notHomeContainer singleContainer">
                    <div className="gallery notHomeGallery singleGallery">
                        {single.map(single_recent => <SingleRecentItems key={single_recent.id} single_recent={single_recent} />)}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div></>
    );
}

class SingleRecentItems extends Component {
   
    render() {
        let { acf } = this.props.single_recent;
        return (
            <>
                <h1>{acf.title}</h1>
                <h4>{acf.style}</h4>
                <div className="photos">
                    <span className="recentPhoto">
                        <img 
                            src={acf.photo}
                            alt={acf.title} 
                        />
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div className="otherInfo">
                    {acf.other}
                </div>
                <div className="location">
                    Photo Taken in: {acf.location_other}<br />
                    {acf.location_city}<br />
                    {acf.location_state}<br />
                    {acf.location_country}
                </div>
                <div className="keywords">
                    {acf.subject}
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

I'd like to take the results of `{acf.other}` and turn the tags into functional tags so that it will format the results (more or less) the way the user intended. Can I somehow assign `{acf.other}` to a var, parse and concat, and return the results? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *general* rule is that you *don't* want to treat your data as code. If this were third-party data, a malicious user might write a `<script src="steal-their-cookies.xyz">` into your webpage, which you'd much rather see as "<script src="steal-their-cookies.xyz">" on the page rather than as executed code! Inserting user-generated data into your page as code is a great way to expose yourself to cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks and other page-breaking and data-stealing hazards.

However, in your case, the data is *supposed* to be code, and is *supposed* to come from a trusted source. To enable your use-case, React has a [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) that allows you to treat this data as code. As in [this LogRocket blog](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-in-a-react-application/), this makes sense for a CMS that has trusted editors submitting rich text, but you should be aware of the hazards and use the property with extreme caution.

```
<!-- Beware the caveats above. -->
<div className="otherInfo" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: acf.other}} />
```

Comment: this seems like its the solution I didn't know I was looking for. It seems closest to achieving what I want with a good deal of flexibility. However, I can't seem to find a way to incorporate the `__html:` key @jeff-bowman

Comment: @Alverstone Sorry, forgot to add that in the snippet. I've edited the answer; the outer braces are for JSX substitution, the inner braces are for an object literal, where the key is `__html` and the value is `acf.other`.

Comment: tyvm. I figured out a way to inject the `__html` into a variable with the `acf.other`, but this is more elegant and worked perfectly. You're a rock star.

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the result String to escape the HTML characters.  It could look something like this:

```
       parsedResult = response.data
                .replace("\\u003c", "<")
                .replace("\\u003d", "=")
                .replace("\\u003e", ">")
                .replace("\\u0026", "&");
```

It might be the case you'll need to escape more characters.  A quick lookup will give you the needed codes.

Hope this helps!